# ReactiveUI, WPF and Validation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation, reactiveui

I've seen that ReactiveUI had validation features in the past. Currently, with version 6.5, I cannot find anything related to it.

Do you know if there's a more or less official way to deal with validation tasks in WPF using ReactiveUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall consensus on RxUI slack group is that people are exposing extra validation properties, e.g. split `UserName` and `UserNameError` (which is `null` if there is no error). Then use the platform’s validation/error mechanism to bring to user’s attention.

Comment: Is there a common way to do that regarding WPF? Maybe using Interaction Behaviors or attaching Style Triggers to those validation-oriented properties? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cant take a look at this repo https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Validation, also available on NuGet gallery.

This solution is based on MVVM pattern, so your ViewModels must implement ISupportsValidation, add rules (ValidationHelper properties) and bind to the validation rules from the View.

ViewModel

```
public class SampleViewModel : ReactiveObject, ISupportsValidation
{
    public ValidationContext ValidationContext => new ValidationContext();

    // Bindable rule
    public ValidationHelper ComplexRule { get; set; }

    public SampleViewModel()
    {
         // name must be at least 3 chars - the selector heee is the property name and its a single property validator
         this.ValidationRule(vm => vm.Name, _isDefined, "You must specify a valid name");
    }
}
```

View

```
public class MainActivity : ReactiveAppCompatActivity<SampleViewModel>
{
    public EditText nameEdit { get; set; }

    public TextInputLayout til { get; set; }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our View from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        WireUpControls();

        // bind to an Android TextInputLayout control, utilising the Error property
        this.BindValidation(ViewModel, vm => vm.ComplexRule, til);
    }
}
```

The View sample is taking advantage of the DroidExtensions (automatically added for Mono.Droid projects), but you can bind the error message to any control of your View.

I hope it helps.

Best regards.

Comment: The OP specifically said WPF. You give him a DroidExtensions package?  Droid is shorthand for "Android", not WPF.

Comment: I am just referencing to the view sample. However, the same BindValidation method exists for any platform.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I don't know what I'm doing wrong on this (ReactiveUI validation), but I'll figure it out, blog it, and post the url here.

Comment: Perfect! I am working on a sample to clarify the main concepts of this package. You can check it out [here](https://github.com/alexmartinezm/ReactiveUI.Validation) in the samples folder.